# How to use AJAX with jQuery validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to validate a login (checking the server to see whether the login is free or not - it returns JSON) with the jQuery validation plug. I read about using a remote function in jQuery, but I failed to implement it properly. I want to do this without PHP, and just use a link to the server, as you can see in my code below.

I managed to create code that works, but I had to make `getJSON` synchronous. Here is my code:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("isItFree", function(value, element) {
  $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
  var isItFree = null;
  $.getJSON('http://.../register/check/'+value, function(data) {
    $.parseJSON(data);
    isItFree = !data[value]; // server response is false if login isn't taken
  });
  $.ajaxSetup({async: true});
  return this.optional(element) || isItFree;
});
```

- Is there a way to do it without making `getJSON` synchronous and with the jQuery validation plugin?

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/#options

Comment: You could couple that with dataFilter field of jQuery ajax to sanitize the reponse.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site. You've also got a number of questions in your question, which is pushing it toward being too broad. Can you [edit] your question to concentrate on a single issue?

Comment: Oh, I can do it for sure. Edit is done, hope it's better now.